# Using the "find" command to accumulate values "without for loops"

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, find

I will use `find` to get the indices from a matrix (named `lag`) and then sum their corresponding values from another matrix (`H`). This will require a `for` loop. (The matrices are 2D.)

(`max` is used here to implying a generic example)

```
D=zeros(max, 1)
for j = 1:max
    ind = find(lag==j)
    D(j) = sum(H(ind))
end
```

This is a 4 point example. Points are at (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2). This is part of a geostatistical method. The distance between all points has been calculated in `H`. `lags` is `H` but rounded down and then a plus 1 to associate the distances with their closest integer (a classification called lag). I now want to sum the total distance for each `lag` into vector `D`.

`lag` (4x4) - stores the general lag interval

```
1  2  2  2
2  1  2  2
2  2  1  2
2  2  2  1
```

`H` (4x4) - stores the distance between points

```
0   1   1   1.414
1   0   1.414   1
1   1.414   0   1
1.414   1   1   0
```

Can I do this without `for` loops?

Comment: Please: 1. add some dummy definitions for `H` and `lag` indicating their sizes, i.e. provide a [mcve]; 2. don't use `max` as a variable name, as that will conflict with matlab's built-in `max` function, 3. do use semicolons at the end of commands to suppress their output. The likely answer is "yes" to your question, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
D = accumarray(lag(:), H(:));
```

This accumulates (sums) values of the second argument (`H` linearized to a column vector) for each group defined by the values of the first argument (`lag` linearized to a column vector).

Comment: Nice! At first I thought about `accumarray`, but then I realized that I still have no idea of how to use it:) This is how it should be done!

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, `accumarrary` is dificult at first, with its up to six input arguments :-)

Comment: I can finally tick you as the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with

```
ulag = unique(lag); %contains [1 2]
D = arrayfun(@(l)sum(H(lag==l)),ulag);
```

`unique(lag)` will distil `lag` into unique values, in your small example `[1 2]`. Then `arrayfun` will go over the array `ulag`, and for each element `l` it will perform `sum(H(lag==l))`, which does exactly what you want: sums those elements from `H` for which the corresponding element in `lag` is equal to `l`. Note that this only works fine if `lag` contains integers, otherwise `unique` might not find identical elements due to machine precision (but from your question I gathered that it is probably inherently an integer).

Also note that the above two lines could also have been written in one:

```
D = arrayfun(@(l)sum(H(lag==l)),unique(lag));
```

I just thought that after separation it might be easier to digest.

Also also note that the above makes use of that the values of `lag` start from 1 up to a maximal value without gaps. If this is not the case, then you should do something like

```
D(unique(lag)) = arrayfun(@(l)sum(H(lag==l)),unique(lag));
```

but in this case you have to make sure that `lag` doesn't contain non-positive values.

Comment: Thanks Andras. Like a charm. I need to learn to use arrayfun more often! (Sorry, too low rep to vote yet.)

Comment: @user24007, glad I could help. But actually Luis's solution with `accumarray` is the best: that was designed to do this:)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way to do this without a `for` loop, but you can do it without using `find`.

```
D = zeros(N, 1)
for j = 1:N
   D(j) = sum(sum((lag == j).*H));
end
```

The result of `lag == j` will be a 4x4 (or rather NxN) matrix of boolean values such that `(lag == j).*H` will retain the distances for each lag but have zeros for all other elements. Summing all of the elements in `(lag == j).*H` will then give you the same answer for `D(j)`.

Note I have switched `max` to be `N` since `max` is a built-in MATLAB function.